# I am trying to use ASP.NET inline expressions in the .NET Framework, but it's not working

Tags: asp.net, webforms, inline

I have the following code in a webform that will display a number of images and a label for each image:

#### My Images

```
<%LoginUsers user = (LoginUsers)Session["LoginUsers"];
  if (user != null)
  {
      int num, i;
      String[] photos = user.getUserPhotos();
      num = photos.Length;
      for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
      {
          %>
          <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/ImageHandler.ashx?id=<%= user.email%>&name=<%= photos[i]%>"/>
          <asp:Label runat="server" Text="<%= photos[i]%>"></asp:Label>
          <%

      }
  }
  else
  {
      Session["LoginUsers"] = null;
      Response.Redirect("Index.aspx");
  }  
%>
```

When I run the application both of the labels appear with the text: "photos[i]", instead of the content that is on that array of strings.

Apparently I am using  inline expressions wrong, but I can't figure out what is my problem.
Can somebody help me here?

Comment: not sure how I can contribute.  I cannot see any issues with your code.  Perhaps you can create a variable and assign the photos[i] to that and use that instead of the array.

Comment: i dont use this templating engine with asp.net at all, i use Razor with MVC3/4, but from a bit of research, i noticed that all the examples of <%=displayVariable%> has No space between the <%= and the variablename.  Perhaps that will help too.

Comment: I tried that with the following modifications but the same happened. Only this time the text change to "<%=aux%>"
I have tried also without spaces and the same problem is happening.

New code modifications:

              String aux = photos[i];
              %>
              <asp:Label runat="server" Text="<%=aux%>"></asp:Label>
              <%

Comment: ok I am wrong... it happens.. turns out you cannot do what you're attempting to do.  This article says why http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976112

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I can't do this on attributes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of an asp:label, try a html label and see what happens.

`<label><%= photos[i] %></label>`

Answer (score 0):

You should use a repeater control for this purpose, here is a link for reference.
[Repeater example for displaying images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378746/using-repeater-control-to-display-an-image-from-database-c-sharp).